# Get input from page source contained in python var

Tags: python, request, urllib2

I have a Python script that make a request using urllib2, and store in a var the entire source code of the web page using:

```
source = urlopen(request).read().decode()
```

Assuming there is the following html input in the `source` variable

```
<input name="form1" type="hidden" value="value1">
```

How do I get the value of that input contained in my var? Can I have a sample code for doing that?

Edit:

As suggested, a BeautifulSoup code like this should work?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
for value in soup.find(name='value1'):
    value = value.get('value')
```

Comment: Have you tried BeautifulSoup? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: How could I do that? Tried to see how it works but I never really used it so I wouldn't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). So, let's say you want to extract the value of the `value` attribute. Here's how you'd do it:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

request = "http://example.com"
source = urllib2.urlopen(request).read().decode()
# Or you can test with:
# source = "<input name='form1' type='hidden' value='value1'>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
value = soup.find("input", {"name": "form1"}).get("value")
```